# Closing multiple numbered divs with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a simple navigation system using vanilla javascript to open and close div panels.  The current iteration has four panels and four nav links that open them.

The current code I have below works just fine to click a link, open the appropriate panel, click the link again to close that panel.  But I want to take it one step further, such that if panel 2 is open and you click link 4, panel 2 closes and panel 4 opens.  My thoughts were to loop through all the panels and simply close them, but can't seem to get that to work using things like ***for***, ***while***.

Hard coding with just four panels is easy enough, but with time that number can increase and I am sure there is a way to do this more automagically.

```html
<div id='hdn1'>Target 1</div>
<div id='hdn2'>Target 2</div>
<div id='hdn3'>Target 3</div>
<div id='hdn4'>Target 4</div>

<span onclick="openNav(1)">Link 1</span>
<span onclick="openNav(2)">Link 2</span>
<span onclick="openNav(3)">Link 3</span>
<span onclick="openNav(4)">Link 4</span>

<script>
  function openNav(x) {

    if (document.getElementById("hdn" + x).style.display === 'block') {
      document.getElementById("hdn" + x).style.display = "none";
    } else {
      // need to first make sure all other hdn are closed, then open selected
      document.getElementById("hdn" + x).style.display = "block";
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: *"but can't seem to get that to work using things like for, while."* What did your attempt look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you mean with "*but can't seem to get that to work using things like for, while*" but this *is* working.

For **modern browsers** you could do it like this:

```js
function openNav(x) {
  if (document.getElementById("hdn" + x).style.display === 'block') {
    document.getElementById("hdn" + x).style.display = "none";
  } else {
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(`[id^=hdn]:not(hdn${x})`), x => x.style.display = 'none');
    document.getElementById("hdn" + x).style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='hdn1'>Target 1</div>
<div id='hdn2'>Target 2</div>
<div id='hdn3'>Target 3</div>
<div id='hdn4'>Target 4</div>

<span onclick="openNav(1)">Link 1</span>
<span onclick="openNav(2)">Link 2</span>
<span onclick="openNav(3)">Link 3</span>
<span onclick="openNav(4)">Link 4</span>
```

If you really need to support **older browsers** as well, do it like that:

```js
function openNav(x) {
  if (document.getElementById("hdn" + x).style.display === 'block') {
    document.getElementById("hdn" + x).style.display = "none";
  } else {
    var targets = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="hdn"]');
    for (var i = targets.length; i--;) {
      targets[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById("hdn" + x).style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='hdn1'>Target 1</div>
<div id='hdn2'>Target 2</div>
<div id='hdn3'>Target 3</div>
<div id='hdn4'>Target 4</div>

<span onclick="openNav(1)">Link 1</span>
<span onclick="openNav(2)">Link 2</span>
<span onclick="openNav(3)">Link 3</span>
<span onclick="openNav(4)">Link 4</span>
```

See:

- [querySelectorAll (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (used for both solutions)
- [CSS Selectors (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)
- [Array.prototype.forEach (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Arrow functions (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Template Literals (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: I noticed that your examples address the open 3 close 2 aspect, but they don't allow close 3 (one target always remains open).  But it seems if I move your "close all" function into the **else** portion of my current code, I get back the open 3 close 3.

Comment: All answers were great, but I elected to chose yours as it used the existing id's, rather than adding new classes.

Answer (score 4):

A good idea in such cases is to add a common class to the elements so you can easily target them with `document.getElementsByClassName`

Simple demo

```js
function openNav(x) {

  if (document.getElementById("hdn" + x).style.display === 'block') {
    document.getElementById("hdn" + x).style.display = "none";
  } else {
    // need to first make sure all other hdn are closed, then open selected
    var targets = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-target');
    for(let i = 0;i<targets.length;i++){
      targets[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById("hdn" + x).style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
.nav-target {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='hdn1' class="nav-target">Target 1</div>
<div id='hdn2' class="nav-target">Target 2</div>
<div id='hdn3' class="nav-target">Target 3</div>
<div id='hdn4' class="nav-target">Target 4</div>

<span onclick="openNav(1)">Link 1</span>
<span onclick="openNav(2)">Link 2</span>
<span onclick="openNav(3)">Link 3</span>
<span onclick="openNav(4)">Link 4</span>
```

---

A better, yet, approach is to handle the show/hide through classes (*also using more modern features like [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) etc*)

```js
function openNav(x) {
  var targetSelector = '#hdn' + x,
      otherSelector = '.nav-target.open:not('+targetSelector+')';
  
  document.querySelectorAll(otherSelector).forEach(function(node){
    node.classList.remove('open');
  });
  
 document.querySelector(targetSelector).classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
.nav-target {
  display: none;
}
.nav-target.open{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div id='hdn1' class="nav-target">Target 1</div>
<div id='hdn2' class="nav-target">Target 2</div>
<div id='hdn3' class="nav-target">Target 3</div>
<div id='hdn4' class="nav-target">Target 4</div>

<span onclick="openNav(1)">Link 1</span>
<span onclick="openNav(2)">Link 2</span>
<span onclick="openNav(3)">Link 3</span>
<span onclick="openNav(4)">Link 4</span>
```

Comment: You missed a backtick for `document.getElementsByClassName`

Comment: Thanks.  Might I ask what makes the second one better?  You mentioned modern features, but would those work with older browsers?  Our customers span the gamut from up to date techophiles to "I still got disc drives" types.

Comment: @Tom, modern features refers to modern browser versions. So most likely not. The idea is that you have methods to easily toggle/add/remove classes to elements and also easy way to select elements in the DOM (*the `querySelector` accepts full css selectors as paremeter*).

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your panels `class="panel"` and then grab all panels with `.querySelectorAll` to close them before opening another one.

```
function openNav(x) {
  if(document.getElementById("hdn" + x).style.display === 'block') {
      document.getElementById("hdn" + x).style.display = "none"; 
  } else {
      var panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');
      for(var i = 0; i < panels.length; i++){
          panels[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
      document.getElementById("hdn" + x).style.display = "block"; 
  }
}
```